# How can i send a packet to some users in python?

Tags: python, sockets

I have been writting a socket server in python. I want to send data to some users (no to all) but I dont know how to do it. Can i send it with a for loop?

For example:

```
some_clients = [client1, client2, client5, client9]

for client in some_clients:
    client.send("data")
```

It is good?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that works, it's perfectly OK.

If you want something more readable, you could do:

```
for client in filter(shouldrecieve, all_clients):
    client.send(data)
```

or something like:

```
for client in (client for client in all_clients if client.attrspam == barfoo):
    client.send(data)
```